# Checkbutton values on Tkinter not changing

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter, and I'd like the Checkbutton to print a string when it is checked, and a string when it is unchecked. However, `self.value` always returns `PY_VAR0` whether the box is ticked or not.

```
from tkinter import *

class New:
    def __init__(self, master):
        value = StringVar()
        self.value = value
        frame = Frame(master)

        self.c = Checkbutton(
            master, text="Expand", variable=value,onvalue="Yes",
            offvalue="No",command=self.test)
        self.c.pack(side=LEFT)

    def test(self):
        if self.value == "Yes":
            print("Yes!")
        if self.value == "No":
            print("Not!")
        else:
            print(self.value)

root = Tk()
app = New(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
if self.value.get() == "Yes":
```

instead of

```
if self.value == "Yes":
```

Same everywhere you are trying to access the value of the checkbutton.

Also, it would be better to use

```
    if self.value.get() == "Yes":
        print("Yes!")
    else:
        if self.value.get() == "No":
            print("Not!")
        else:
            print(self.value.get())
```

since using your version will print the value twice if it is "Yes".

Comment: I think it would be easier if the if/else(if/else) statement were just an if/elif/else statement:
`if self.value.get()=="Yes": print("Yes!)";    elif self.value.get()=="No": print("Not!");    else: print(self.value.get())`